# WPF Multithreading & ICollectionChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, silverlight

I'm currently using .NET 3.5 for a project and I need to implement a static Queue that gets it's items enqueued by one background thread and dequeued by yet another. Since there isn't an ObservableQueue or something similar in .NET 3.5 I tried to derive my own Queue and implement INotifyCollectionChanged, since my UI should display the contents of the Queue to the user.

But when I try to run it, the first background worker enqueues an item, CollectionChanged gets raised and then I end up with an exception like

> c# the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

My business objects (those things in the queue) all implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the background worker that dequeues them also changes some properties and therefore the same thread also calls PropertyChanged along with CollectionChanged. Strangely enough I don't got any error when PropertyChanged get raised, but CollectionChanged crashes... can someone help me on this?

Comment: Do you access any ui objects from the background worker?

Comment: are you sure the exception is raised when you access the ObservableQueue ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delegate when your background thread modifies the queue ?

Like :

```
if (Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
{
       Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
       {
           //Modify your collection
       }));
 }
```

Comment: Why should only the UI thread modify the collection? ... sorry but that's nonsense, I already made it thread-safe and that's not applicable in my case.

Comment: @naacal no need to be rude. And no, its not nonesense. Modifying the collection raises a collection change, which your UI is listening to, which then creates ui elements for the new added element. And if that happens in a thread which is not the UI thread you get the exception posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You get such an exception when you're trying to interact with GUI from non-dispatcher (i.e. non-GUI) thread. In your case I assume you're just raising CollectionChanged event without checking whether it is GUI-thread or not. In order to resolve this issue you should, as chrisendymion wrote, us `Dispatcher`. I see two possible options here:

1) Every call to your custom queue (add/delete) is made on Dispatcher (`Dispatcher.Invoke`)

2) Wrap code that raises CollectionChanged event to the same `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And why do my business objects just fine with PropertyChanged? The same thread raises PropertyChanged & CollectionChanged. PropertyChanged does fine, CollectionChanged crashes with said error. And yes, I already tried the Dispatcher.Invoke in OnCollectionChanged().

Comment: Maybe Propertychanged is called while your UI is not yet listening to the PropertyChanged Event.Do you first change the properties, then adding it to the collection. Then it is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            Messages.Add(message);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(() => Messages.Add(message)));
        }
```

You can only access the from GUI-Thread because it is possible that the GUI is bound to the collection. And a lot of threads working with the gui isnt that good thing because as result you will often recieve errors.

So just think about: Why do you can't do something like this: listBox1.Items.Add(...) from another thread. Now you know why you can t do access the list from another thread.

(if you really don t know why you can do something like listBox1.Items.Add(...) google for it... you will find a lot of articles

Answer (score 0):

First, i thing you should extend ObservableCollection insted of implementig an INotifyCollectionChanged collection from the begining. And for multi-thread collection see this class, that may be helpful for you (only for work with multi-thread, if you want add the Queue behavior you need to implement it)

public class ThreadSafeObservableCollection : ObservableCollection
    {
        private SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext;

```
    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection()
    {
        SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // current synchronization context will be null if we're not in UI Thread
        if (SynchronizationContext == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This collection must be instantiated from UI Thread, if not, you have to pass SynchronizationContext to con                                structor.");
    }

    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection(SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
    {
        if (synchronizationContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("synchronizationContext");

        this.SynchronizationContext = synchronizationContext;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.ClearItems()), null);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.InsertItem(index, item)), null);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.RemoveItem(index)), null);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.SetItem(index, item)), null);
    }

    protected override void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        this.SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback((param) => base.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex)), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has a good  technical answer for why this isn't working. The "Dispatcher" object assigned to your current thread doesn't have access to the UI.

In .NET if a dispatcher does not exist in your current thread, .NET will new up another Dispatcher, however this will have the same synchronization context as your background thread - not the UI thread where it needs to synchronize access to.

The easiest solution for my money would be to hold a reference to the original dispatcher in the ObservableCollection, and override the base class calls in a different Dispatcher, something like this should work:

```
public class ObservableDispatcherCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : class
    {
        private Dispatcher _dispatcher;

        public ObservableDispatcherCollection(Dispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            _dispatcher = dispatcher; 
        }

        public ObservableDispatcherCollection(Control parent)
        {
            _dispatcher = parent.Dispatcher;
        }

        protected override void     OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
            }));
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
            }));
        }
}
```